# Kendo UI grid edit custom control - autocomplete return plain object instead complex type

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-mvc

I Have problem with bind object from autocomplete custom editor control in grid cell.

Definition on column:

```
              columns.Bound(p => p.Product)
              .EditorTemplateName("Products")
              //.ClientTemplate("#= Product.Name != undefined ? Product.Name : '' #")
              .Width(160);
```

Definition control in Products.cshtml view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoCompleteFor(m => m)
  .DataTextField("Name")

  .DataSource(ds => 
      ds.ServerFiltering(true).Read(read => read.Action("GetProducts", "Product")))
  .Placeholder(View.BaseDocumentItemDetails_Placeholder)
  .IgnoreCase(true)
  .MinLength(2)
  .Suggest(true)

      .Events(ev =>
      {
         // ev.Select("SelectProductName");
         // ev.Change("ChangeProductName");
      })
  .Filter(FilterType.Contains))
```

If I choose existing object from autocomple control then is ok, but if I  write free text 
then control return only simple text to "Save" event. Below debugging screens:

1) Choose existing element: 
[Debugging save event - complex type ok](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mf38tb630eefizx/2.png)

2) After that I wrote free text. In save event we have simple text.

3) Later i choose another existing product from the list and also get simple text: 
[Existing problem](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9j0n1tgv6lplrow/4.png)

Autocomplete control will returns only simple text after that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set ISPrimitive as true to get only the text (DataTextField) value in the selection.  If you wish to get the whole object of the Autocomplete selection then you will need to set IsPrimitive as false.

> To get the only the text part of the Auto Complete Selection Set False

```
   .IsPrimitive(false)
```

> To get the whole object of the Auto Complete Selection Set True

```
 .IsPrimitive(true)
```

See example for more explanation.

**[AutoComplete IsPrimitive Example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/mvvm)**

Answer (score 0):

I checked this tip but didn't work. I need whole object because I have to use "Id" and "Name" product item. Below definition of autocomplete control using in grid cell custom edit:

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoCompleteFor(m => m)
  .DataTextField("Name")

  .DataSource(ds => 
      ds.ServerFiltering(true).Read(read => read.Action("GetProducts", "Product")))
  .Placeholder(View.BaseDocumentItemDetails_Placeholder)
  .IgnoreCase(true)
  .ValuePrimitive(false)
  .MinLength(2)
  .Suggest(true)

      .Events(ev =>
      {
         // ev.Select("SelectProductName");
         //ev.Change("ChangeProductName");
      })
  .Filter(FilterType.Contains))
```